# spring boot don't create bean for interface

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a problem whit spring boot jpa. I can't     `@Autowired` my interface repository. I use a spring boot with multiple project dependency.
the interface dao is my own interface implémentation

I try a lot of things

```
@Repository
public interface DocumentDao extends  Dao<Long, Document>  {

    @Query(querys.findDocumentByUuids)
    public List<Document> findByUuids(@NotEmpty() @Param("uuids") List<String> uuids) ;

    @Query(querys.findDocumentByUuids)
    public Document findByUuid(@NotNull @Param("uuid")String uuid);
```

Field statusDescriptionDao in be.fgov.minfin.virtualprinter.model.StatusMap required a bean of type

Comment: Ofcourse it won't... Why should it, Spring Data will only create dynamic instances for interfaces extending the `Repository` marker interface (or one of the extended ones like `CrudRepository`.

Comment: I have the same erro with extend repository.

Comment: the dao is in a séparate project of the spring boot runner

Comment: Doesn't matter if it is in a separate project, as long as the packages in there are covered by the packages scanned by the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class it will work. My guess is that you aren't following the general packaging guide lines from the Spring Boot team.

Answer (score 0):

The `Dao` seems to be your base interface so, you could annotate it with `@NoRepositoryBean` as described in more detail [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition-tuning).

Ideally, your `Dao` should extend one of the Repository methods: CrudRepository, JpaRepository etc.

You also will not need `@Repository` annotation on your `DocumentDao`.

Comment: I have already to do that but it doesn't work.I have the same error